# Moodle theme upgrade made site unusable

Tags: php, crash, themes, moodle, appearance

I am new to using Moodle, and reviewed a lot about one of their themes--a lot like WP themes--called evolve-D. As soon as I installed the new theme onto the Moodle site (which had excellent reviews and has been widely used/downloaded), I get a screen that makes the site clearly unusable:

http://www.recruitingfoundations.com/courses/login/index.php

I can't log in to switch it back to the old theme, and I've been researching the issue for the past nine hours...I haven't found anything particularly useful. Does anyone know of any way that I can get into the site to switch it back to the old theme? Please, I am desperate!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the theme in your `config.php`

```
$CFG->theme = '';
```

This will use the default so you can login.

Also if you add this to your `config.php`

```
$CFG->allowthemechangeonurl = true;
```

Then you can pass the theme in the url with ?theme=themename eg:

http://www.recruitingfoundations.com/courses/login/index.php?theme=standard

Which is useful for testing.